# How to treat generally the function of random variable(s)?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I did not really understand the functions of $X+Y$, $X^2$, etc. For example, $F(X^2)$, $f(X+Y)$, etc. How should I treat them? Can you explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat them as random variables. What's a random variable $X$? It's a map from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$, $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. What's $Y = F(X)$? It's a map $Y: \Omega \to^{X} \mathbb{R} \to^{F} \mathbb{R}$, so it's a random variable.

Comment: And how can I, for example, express $f(X^2)$? Where f is the density.

Comment: @545941stuser Density is a function. $f(X^2)$ is also a random variable. If density is for example $f(x) = e^{-x}$ then your r.v. is $e^{-X^2}$

Comment: What i meant is how to calculate, for example, the expected value of $X^2$? I know that the expected value of $X$ is $\int dx f(x) x$, but ehat about $X^2$?

Comment: @545941stuser yes, it's another question. You should use the so-called LOTUS which claims that if the r.v. $X$ has the density $f(x)$ then the expected value $\mathbb{E} (g(X)) = \int g(x)f(x)dx$. $g(x)$ is an arbitrary function

Comment: And how does it look in general? For example, the nth moment around c is $\mu(X)=\int dx (x-c)^n f(x)$, and it will be $\mu(g(X))=\int dx (g(x)-c)^n f(x)$?

Comment: @545941stuser denote $h(X) = \mu (g(X))$, so as I wrote $\mathbb{E} (h(X)) = \int h(x)f(x)dx$

Comment: I don't quite get it - how does the expected value comes to the n-th moment?

Comment: yes, I also didn't get what you want...Do you want to compute $\mathbb{E} ((g(X) - c)^n)$ ? If so, then we denote $h(x) = (g(x) - c)^n$ and $\mathbb{E} (h(X)) = \int h(x)f(x)dx$

Comment: Is $E((g(X)-c)^n)$ the n-th moment of $g(X)$ around c?

Comment: @545941stuser Unfortunately, I'm not aware, I've never come across with such a terminology. I know, that the n-th moment of r.v. $X$ is $\mathbb{E} (X^n)$

Comment: The variance of $X$ is the second moment about the expected value of $X$, for example. I think it's correct with about instead of around.